# How to reload a view class in Django with different model type?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-class-based-views

I'm using a project based approach to learn django by making an e-commerce site. The problem I am having is when I load my index page it shows default item using a class based view. Now what i want is that whenever I click on a category the view should be loaded with products in that category.

All other back end is completed i just want to know how implement this in my class based view.

Below is a snippet of my view

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Prod
    paginate_by = 6
    template_name = "index.html"
```

In this case Prod loads all the rows from my table and what i want is that when electronics is clicked on the page only rows containing electronics be shown but by default it should show all product like it does.

Comment: You need to use JS to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Write a second "Category" ListView that takes the category's id and/or slug as argument (via the urlconf - this is documented) and displays products for this category. You can reuse the products listing part of your current home template by extracting it into it's own (fragment) template that you include in both the home and category templates.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Can you explain how I will go about writing that Class as i don't know which function will take the category's id or how i will call that view from my html ?

Comment: @AyazAfzal Django is pretty well documented, plus there are tons of third-part tutorials. Perhaps doing the official tutorial and reading the official doc would be a good starting point ?